# Missing gcc file for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, path

Good day. I am trying to learn C++, but I can't compile my program. I watched tutorials to download msys64 (my computer is Windows 64bit) and minGW but I can't find the gcc.exe file. From the tutorials I read and watched, it's supposed to be in the bin folder but that folder is empty, along with the 32bit version of the same folder. I used the search bar at the bottom to find the gcc executable but my computer can't find it. How can I fix this?

[image: Here is a picture of the folder]

Comment: You might find visual studio easier for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

You could download gcc for windows here:
[https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/][1]